# Pycharm difficulties with pip and Pillow

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, python-imaging-library

I am using Pycharm in order to create a project that I need for school. To complete my project, I need `pip` and `Pillow`.

I have gone to the settings in Pycharm and I have installed `pip` and `Pillow` accordingly and updated them to the most up-to-date version. ([See Fig 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYA5t.png)).

When I use terminal to check for `pip`, it says that it is not installed, however in my code, I can import it. When I try to import it, I cannot import it as it says that `pip` Statement has no effect.

There is also a syntax line highlighting `Pillow` even though I have installed it in Pycharm

I have tried everything I can to make it work and I am truly frustrated.
Can anyone please help me? I am running the latest versions of Pycharm and Python (3.8)

[image: Fig 1 shows the packages being installed (pip and Pillow).]

[image: Fig 2 shows my code error.]

[image: Fig 3 is me hovering over Pillow, which is telling me to install Pillow, even though its already installed.]

Comment: Hi @TheAvgCoder, welcome to StackOverflow! This kind of questions are better answered on communities like [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/). You can read what StackOverflow is for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

To answer your question, to import a package, you don't need to write "pip import <package_name>", but "import <package_name". As you correctly noticed, Pillow is already installed in your environment.

Comment: Also please avoid posting errors as images. Post the error along with the question rather than screenshots. Follow this for link for explaination. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7515189

Answer (score 0):

You don't use pip as a library in your python code (you can, but its probably not what you want). Something like `pip import Pillow` does not make sense. You should use pip **as a program** outside your python code (from the terminal) to install python libraries that you program wants to use.

You can also install libraries directly from PyCharm (which will call pip for you).
In the python interpreter settings in PyCharm (first Figure) there is a small `+` icon in the right that you can click on. Then you type the name of the library you want to install, such as Pillow, and click on the "Install package" button. After that in your python code you can write just `import libraryname`, or `from libraryname import something`, etc.

However, note that sometimes the **package name** of a library if different from the **import name** of that library. To install and use the `scikit-learn` library you use `scikit-learn` to install it, but when importing it in Python you should use `import sklearn` instead. I haven't used Pillow before, but from the [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) it seems the Pillow library is also like that. That is, you install it with the `Pillow` name, but when importing it in Python [you should use `PIL`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html) instead. That is, something like `from PIL import Image` should work after `Pillow` is installed.

Comment: Hi, I have tried executing it from the terminal as well. I have installed Pillow from the interpreter settings and it says no module found. Please look at my attached figures, I have also attached a new Figure 4. https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQbfu.png

Comment: While most libraries use the same name for installation and import, some libraries have a different "package name" (for installation) and "import name" (in Python). This seems to be the case with Pillow from its documentation. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggesting to Import PIL instead of Pillow. I will try tomorrow to see if it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few weeks ago when i tried to import a module in pycharm.
After installing a package on your pc with pip you still need to install it in pycharm.
Hover over the import statment and click the "install pillow" button and it will install it in pycharm. After that it will work fine.
If you want you could install it manually following the [documentation.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html)

Comment: I have also clicked Install Pillow from the hover over menu and it still says that its not installed.

Comment: There is no need to install something twice. You just need to make sure that the environment you installed in your PC is the same that is currently selected in PyCharm. Then it doesn't matter if you install it with PyCharm or from the command line. The only difference is that if you use PyCharm to install some library you are sure it will install it in the current environment used in your project.

Comment: I am trying to follow up, did this solve your issue, or are you still having problems?